# Escape string in jQuery while passing a variable as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

I am trying to pass a variable inside a JavaScript function. The problem I'm failing to figure out how to escape string to send that variable inside a double quote. There are tons of answers on this but I couldn't use them correctly.

```
for (var k = 0; k < districts[division].length; k++) {
    $('#district_list').append('<li class="byebooklist"><a href="javascript:getUniversity(' + districts[division][k] + ');">' + districts[division][k] + '</a></li>');
}
```

How to pass the parameter to the `getUniversity()` function inside a double quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with escaped quotes:

```
$('#district_list').append(
  '<li class="byebooklist"><a href="javascript:getUniversity(\''+districts[division][k]+'\');">'+districts[division][k]+'</a></li>'
);
//                                                           ^^                          ^^
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you need to wrap the value in the function argument in quotes, but you'll need to escape them, using `\'`:

```js
for (var k = 0; k < districts[division].length; k++) {
  $('#district_list').append('<li class="byebooklist"><a href="javascript:getUniversity(\'' + districts[division][k] + '\');">' + districts[division][k] + '</a></li>');
}
```

*However*, you can both avoid the problem and improve the logic by not putting any JS in the `href` at all and instead using an unobtrusive event handler. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```
var html = districts[division].map(function(div) {
  return '<li class="byebooklist"><a href="#" data-division="' + div + '">' + div + '</a></li>';
}).join('');
$('#district_list').append(html);

$(document).on('click', '.byebooklist a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  getUniversity($(this).data('division'));
});
```